# Can't determine Intel Chipset Information and thus max memory supported by system

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I have old lenovo 3000 C300 All-in-one PC. It has

1. Intel Atom 330 @ 1.66
2. 2 memory slots, PC2-5300 (667mhz) SODIMM 200 pin memory.
3. CPU-Z Rated FSB is 531.92 Mhz

Here are results from different scanners -

1. CPU-Z : **i945G** PCI Express
2. Intel chipset utility : **82945G/GZ**
3. Crucial Scanner : Max 2GB RAM
4. Lenovo Manual : Intel **945GC** Express Chipset
5. Device drivers and Dxdiag didn't reveal anything.

I can't determine whether chipset is whether 945G/GZ/GC/GM. All these chipsets support different memory frequency and size.

**945 G/GZ/GM** **supports** **4GB** of maximum memory and **945GC** **supports only** **2GB**.

If my system supports 4GB, does it mean it requires 2x2GB sticks or 1x4GB stick will work? Is there any memory per slot limit?

**Update -** I checked on mobo itself, it's 945GC. Also HWiNFO seems more accurate (it showed Intel 945GC (Lakeport-GC) + ICH7).

Comment: Have you tried looking at the mobo itself? There you should find the model imprinted and this could help you to identify if it is a G/GC/GZ/GM mobo - as eg here [I945GCS](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/A1DgHjqbWxL._SL1500_.jpg)

Comment: @Zina That's exactly the same mobo. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Pretty sure the diamondvilles were a single slot and 2gb - in line with MS's standards for netbooks running XP at the time. http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Intel-Atom-330-D945GCLF2,6390.html refers to intel's reference design.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek my mobo is different than the one mentioned in article, mine has 2 slots. Can't find anything in speccy/wmic (To be filled by O.E.M).

Comment: yup. That's curious. Does your graphics card happen to be nvidia?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek No, ATI mobility raedon 4530 512Mb. Mobo is same as the one linked by zina

Answer (score 0):

I would trust the proprietary Intel utility, however in this situation your best option is to buy two 2GB sticks and try them both. If it boots and only recognizes 2GB then you have your answer.

Comment: Added FSB values if it helps identify chipset in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum supported by your system is 4 GB - Two 2 GB DDR2 667 MHz modules.

Check out this [link](http://www.memorystock.com/memory/IBM3000C3003012xxx.html)

Comment: It's a lenovo PC not IBM. The page you linked also mentions Intel 945GC Chipset which only supports 2GB of memory.

Comment: Lenovo acquired IBM's personal computer business, so the link will show as IBM Lenovo. That is the correct url